# Using AngularFire2, how do I transform data in an ObservableList containing other Observables

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm a bit new to this so bear with me. I'll try my best to explain. I'm using AngularFire2 and [retrieving data as a list](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md). In my case I'm trying to get a list of transactions associated with an account (See sample data below).

**Sample Data**

```
accounts: {
  account1: {
    name: "Account 1",
    transactions: {
      transaction1: {
        date: somedate
      },
      transaction2: {
        date: somedate
      }
    }
  }
}

transactions: {
  transaction1: {
    name: "Transaction 1"
  },
  transaction2: {
    name: "Transaction 2"
  },
  transaction3: {
    name: "Transaction 3"
  }
}
```

My first step was to get the list of transactions from the account:

```
af.database.list('/accounts/account1/transactions');
```

This gives me an observable array of objects something like this:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Then I would like to completely replace those two objects with the actual transaction details from the transactions node. So something like this:

```
af.database.list('/accounts/account1/transactions')
.map(res => {
  return res.map(items => {
    return af.database.list('/transactions/items.$key');
  })
})
```

This sorta gets me what I want, except I now have an observable array of observables instead of objects like this:

```
[Observable, Observable]
```

I can get this to work in my template as long as I use async and the Elvis operator like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let transaction of transactions | async">{{ (transaction | async)?.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

I also need to get the name of the account as a part of each object or observable so I end up changing it to something like this:

```
af.database.list('/accounts/account1/transactions')
.map(res => {
  return res.map(transaction => {
    transaction.details = af.database.list('/transactions/' + transaction.$key);
    transaction.account = af.database.list('/accounts/' + accountKey);
  })
})
```

OK, so this actually works, but now I want to transform this data so my service returns something a littler cleaner. What you don't see in the sample data below is that the transactions and accounts each have a ton more data points in them. I don't need or want those in the response so I want to clean it up a bit. In the end I would like to respond with an observable array of objects just like the inital angularfire2 call would have given. Right now I have an observable array of objects that look like this:

```
{
  date: somedate,
  details: Observable,
  account: Observable
}
```

I really want to have something more like this:

```
{
  date: somedate,
  name: "Transaction 1",
  accountName: "Account 1"
}
```

So, I need to figure out how to get the values out of those observables and I'm banging my head agaisnt a wall trying to figure it out. Anyone have any advice? I'm sure I am missing something simple here.

Most solutions I've found have recommended using flatMap or concatMap, but that ends up giving me an observable of individual objects instead of an observable array that contains the objects.